# Vuejs return result count from filterby

Tags: vue.js

How do you get the number of results returned after filtering a collection?

I created a side filter:

```
filters:{
  count: function(value){
    return value.length;
  }
},
```

I then called the count filter using:

```
<span v-text="results | count"></span>
```

But this is not returning the count of the returned result from my filtered result.

Here's my `results` object

```
results: [
      {
        id: 1,
        purchaseDate: 2016-10-15 09:34:00,
        fullName: 'Test 1',
        email: 'test@test.com',
      },

      {
        id: 2,
        purchaseDate: 2016-10-17 09:34:00,
        fullName: 'Test 2',
        email: 'test@test.com',
      }
    ]
```

When my filter returns `Test 2`, I should get a count of 1 instead of 2 (total number of results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to count the filtered object:

```
<span v-text="results | filterBy 'Test 2' | count"></span>
```